# Change image visibility from an Usercontrol on C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am coding an application, its a quiz, I have a main Window where I load different `UserControls` (Pages). so my problem is that I have one image on the `MainWindow`, I want to change the `Visibility` of this image from `Collapsed` to `Visible` from one of the `UserControls` but with no luck...

Here is my `MainWindow`:

```
<Window x:Class="MuseonQuiz_v3.PageSwitcher"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MuseonQuiz_v3.Pages"
    xmlns:k="http://schemas.microsoft.com/kinect/2013"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="710" Width="1127" IsEnabled="True" DataContext="{Binding}" FontFamily="KaiTi" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"
     WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">


<Grid>         
    <Grid>            
        <k:KinectRegion Name="kinectRegion">
            <ContentControl x:Name="mainContentControl"/>
        </k:KinectRegion>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <k:KinectSensorChooserUI HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="sensorChooserUi" />
        <k:KinectUserViewer VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" k:KinectRegion.KinectRegion="{Binding ElementName=kinectRegion}" Height="600" Width="600" />
        <Image Name="colorStreamImage" Width="640" Height="480" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and this is my `UserControl`:

```
public partial class Selectie : UserControl, ISwitchable
{
    string backgroundSelectie = "pack://application:,,,/MuseonQuiz_v3;component/Images/Selectie/selectie_background.jpg";

    public Selectie()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selectieBackground();
        animatieButtons();
    }

    #region ISwitchable Members
    public void UtilizeState(object state)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My question is... how do I change the `Visibility` of the `colorStreamImage` that is located in the `MainWindow` from the `UserControl`... I have tried making an instance of the `MainWindow`, but that does not work, maybe I have to use some binding, but I am not sure, I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Search the web for MVVM. Then create a view model that is shared by your main window and the UserControl, which has a visibility property. Bind the Image Visibility to this property, and change the property value from the UserControl.

Comment: Thanx, i will give it a try

Comment: i read about it, but the concept is still no clear for me, could you give an example?

Comment: You need a reference to the current instance of your `MainWindow` and acces your `Image` from that reference to set the `Visibility` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) mentioned, your best bet is to go down the MVVM path. This is a good tutorial to get started [In the Box – MVVM Training](https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/).

First, you can create a view model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. In this case, you may want it to have at least one property of type Visibility.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Visibility _imageVisibility;
    public Visibility ImageVisibility
    {
        get { return _imageVisibility; }
        set { _imageVisibility = value; OnPropertyChanged("ImageVisibility"); }
    }

    private BitmapImage _imageSource;
    public BitmapImage ImageSource{...}

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler eventHandler = PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now you'll want to set this view model as the data context on the main window. To do this, Paul Stovell has a good post on the different approaches: http://paulstovell.com/blog/mvvm-instantiation-approaches. Once we set it on the main window, the Selectie element will inherit the data context. Using the simplest approach:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Your Image element might then bind to the property like this:

```
<Image Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="200" Width="200"></Image>
```

The Selectie element can now change the ImageVisbility property on the view model since it shares the same data context as MainWindow. (I used the code-behind as an example. You'll probably want to push as much of that logic out of the view and into the view model or further downstream)

```
public partial class Selectie : UserControl
{
    public Selectie()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Selectie_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).ImageVisibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            ((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).ImageVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            ((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).ImageVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try your suggestion today